# How to prove $ \bigl\lvert \frac{az+b}{cz+d}\bigr\rvert = \frac{\operatorname{Im}(z)}{\vert cz+d \vert^2}$? $z\in \mathbb{H}$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

[image: LECTURES ON SHIMURA CURves]

$\Gamma(z, K):=\{g\in\Gamma \ \vert \ g(z) \in K \}$

How to show $\biggl\lvert \dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}\biggr\rvert = \dfrac{\operatorname{Im}(z)}{\bigl(\lvert cz+d \rvert\bigr)^2}$ for $z\in \mathbb{H}$ and
 $\begin{pmatrix}
   a & b \\
   c & d \\
  \end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: $\mathbb{H}$ or $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: Hint: multiply numerator and denominator by $c\overline z+d$.

Comment: @Wojowu  $\frac{(az+b)(c\overline{z}+d)}{(cz+d)(c\overline{z}+d)}=\frac{iy + adx+bcx+bd+ac\vert z\vert^2}{\vert cz+d \vert^2}$ where $z=x+iy$.

Comment: @Netchaiev Are they different?

Comment: @Wojowu $\frac{(az+b)(c\overline{z}+d)}{(cz+d)(c\overline{z}+d)}=\frac{iy + adx+bcx+bd+ac\vert z\vert^2}{\vert cz+d \vert^2}$ Thus $\vert \frac{az+b}{cz+d} \vert ≥ \frac{Im(z)}{\vert cz+d \vert^2}$. I am stuck here.

Comment: I believe there is a mistake in the paper - what it should say is that $Im\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right)=Im(z)/|cz+d|^2$, otherwise the equality doesn't hold.

Comment: @Metamorphosis $\mathbb{H}$ makes thing of a filed, for example quaternions ... Moreover, here I fail to see where $\mathcal{H}$ is defined.

Comment: I'm guessing $\mathcal H$ is the upper half plane.